# How to the set permission of content types for a specific user role?

Tags: users

How to set the permission of content types for a specific user role?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set permission from admin panel then goto **/admin/people/permission** after find your **content** (view/edit) and set the user role **(anonymous/ Authenticated/ Administration)** permission. but if you want to set it problematically then visit https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/theme-product  (Drupal 7 - A Simple Content Type: Permissions & Access)

Answer (score 0):

For D7 you can use the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module.

As an alternative (which I recommend), for D7 or D8, you can use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.